# Sum Up All characters of a string?

Tags: c#, wpf, sum

Idea is simple, user enters the number(string) in a textbox, for example 155321, the app would the sum 1+5+5+3+2+1, and give out the sum of them, since i am still learning, i don't know where to start. The app is made in WPF. Hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple LINQ answer:

```
string s = // your input string
var result = s.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).Sum();
```

This is the universal answer, without a dependence of WPF.

Comment: There's no overload of `int.Parse` which takes a `char` parameter so this won't compile.

Comment: You should cast `x` to `int`. As Lee corrected pointed out there isn't such an overload. `s.Select(x=>(int)x).Sum()`

Comment: @Christos this will sum the decimal values of each char. If you want to avoid that : `s.Select(x=>(int)x-'0').Sum()`

Comment: @Christos
This is about it, the problem I am having now is to show it to the user, i tried with
     MessageBox.Show(result);
but it says that i cannot convert from int to string, I tried
     (Convert.ToInt(result));
and it works, but gives random numbers, I enter 12 it gives me 49, kinda funny.

Comment: @Neyoh u are on point, this is exactly it. Thank You so much!
all of You, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I propose two solution :

**1- standard :**

```
 string resultNumber = "12"; // your number
        int sumNumber = 0;// result of calculating
        for (int i = 0; i < resultNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            sumNumber = int.Parse(resultNumber.Substring(i, 1)) + sumNumber;
        }
```

**2- Recursive**

```
  public static int SumNumber(string number)
        {

           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(number))
                return 0;
           else if(number.Length == 1)
                return int.Parse(number);
           else
               return SumNumber(number.Substring(1)) + int.Parse(number.Substring(0, 1));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is as follows:

```
var str = "19035683";
var sum = str.Sum(x => char.GetNumericValue(x));
```

Another similar solution is:

```
var str = "12312512341231";
var sum = str.Sum(x => x - '0');
```